# How can I determine python versions and installation date on windows

Tags: python

Does python know when it was installed? On windows

```
where python
```

tells me the path, but if i have several versions and environments is there a way to tell me all of them as well as their installation dates?

Comment: Shouldn't all programs know when they were born (written to disk as well as instantiated)?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: `python --version` does what it says, and the python.exe created date should be when it was installed.

Comment: @James thanks. It's what I thought, programs themselves are never imprinted with their installation date- that is something only the OS tracks. And on Unix, I dont think even that is tracked - just last access date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PowerShell` to retrieve the python executable **creation date**, it should be the same as the **installation date**, i.e.:

To get the **installation** date:

```
$file = Get-Item (gcm python).Path
$file.CreationTime
#Saturday, May 23, 2015 09:44:06
```

To get the python **version**:

```
python --version
#Python 2.7.10
```